Why is django class-based_view not seeing my uploads?
class MultipleFileInput(forms.ClearableFileInput):
  """ 
  Work around for `widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})`
  >> `widget=MultipleFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})`
  """
  input_text = 'Select'
  clear_checkbox_label = 'Clear'
  initial_text = 'Current'
  allow_multiple_selected = True


class UserUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
  file = forms.FileField(
    widget=MultipleFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), 
    required=True,
    validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['csv'])],
  ) 

  class Meta:
    model = UserUpload
    fields = ['file']

class MyFilesView(FormView):
    template_name = 'data_related/my_files.html'
    form_class = UserUploadForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_files') 
        
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form = self.get_form()

        files = self.request.FILES.getlist('file')
        print(files)
        print("Files received:", request.FILES.getlist('file'))  # Debug output to confirm files are received

        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid")  # Debug statement
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            print("Form is not valid")  # Debug statement
            for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    print(f"Error in {field}: {error}")
                    messages.error(request, f"Error in {field}: {error}")
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_files = UserUpload.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        files = [{'short_name': file.file.name, 'file_size': file.file_size, 'uuid': file.uuid} for file in user_files]

        # Pagination
        paginator = Paginator(files, 10)  # Show 10 files per page
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        context.update({
            'user_files': files,
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'form': self.get_form(), #form_class((self.request.POST, self.request.FILES) or None) # show UserUploadForm, must instantiate form with POST and FILES
        })

2024-04-26 03:53:45 []
2024-04-26 03:53:45 Files received: []
2024-04-26 03:53:45 Form is not valid
2024-04-26 03:53:45 Error in file: This field is required.
2024-04-26 03:53:56 [<InMemoryUploadedFile: geographies.csv (text/csv)>]
2024-04-26 03:53:56 Files received: [<InMemoryUploadedFile: geographies.csv (text/csv)>]
2024-04-26 03:53:56 Form is not valid
2024-04-26 03:53:56 Error in file: No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.

This thing is crazy. I have been uploading files and it did say it found my files, yet it refuse to validate the upload form.
This problem is related to this thread No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form and I've done everything stated there.

can you show your html template, it looks like your form does not have enctype="multipart/form-data"

I did that too. I just copied past from django docs and their example works, somehow not mine. I poke around longer and the issue is forms.ModelForm. But it also means I have to sacrifice the functionality I was expecting it to give.
